# Web API authentication pass to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a authentication service though web api, if the user is valid, the web API will response a access token. My Question is that How can I pass other Identity information to MVC application.

e.g.

In the MVC application, I got the controller below.

```
[Authorized("Admin,myROle")]
ActionResult GetAllUser()
{
........
}
```

How can I get the role information like "Admin" from the WebAPI?  Moreover, If I used Angular, How can I get the Role information from the webAPI response? If I use asp.net MVC, How I can pass the role info to the controller?

Comment: Just pass back a json object with all the params you need. You could even serialize it + base-64 encode for obfuscations sake and decode it in the client (angular) app.

Comment: @Coldstar thanks your Idea, I know I can pass role information through the token response  from the WebAPI. If I want to have a more secure role info, I can some decryption and encryption to the role information. If I want to pass the role info to MVC  controller, how can I do it?

Comment: My solution was not particular to asp.net MVC specifically, but i was speaking in terms of overall workflow. Sorry if I was misleading but I do not have asp.net MVC installed to further demostrate my solution